# one tail hypothesis testing, Gaussian versus t-distribution

Tags: hypothesis-testing, normal-distribution, t-distribution

Since the `t-distribution` represents more uncertainty than the `Gaussian distribution` I am accustomed to expecting a greater p-value when hypothesis testing. Consider autumn and winter temperatures as illustrated as input to my program for the `apache commons math library`.

```
autumn +1.0, +4.5, -1.0, +3.5, -2.0, +2.0, +1.5, +2.0, +0.0, -1.0, -2.0, +3.0, +4.5, +6.5, +6.0, -1.0, +2.0
winter -7.0, +1.0, -2.5, -2.0, +1.0, +2.0, -3.5, -4.0, -1.0, +2.5, -1.0, -5.5, -2.0, +1.0, +0.0, -3.0, +1.5
```

**The test of the hypothesis that the true mean is zero.** The results are as illustrated.

```
hypothesis is that the true mean equals 0
autumn observed mean  +1.7, gaussian dist p-value 0.008, t-dist p-value 0.017
winter observed mean  -1.3, gaussian dist p-value 0.045, t-dist p-value 0.062
```

`Equal to zero, Autumn`

The above agrees with the intuition that the t-dist p-value should be greater because the assumed distribution represents more uncertainty.

`Equal to zero, Winter`

The above agrees with the intuition that the t-dist p-value should be greater because the assumed distribution represents more uncertainty.

**The test of the hypothesis that the true mean is less-than-or-equal to zero.** The results are as illustrated.

```
hypothesis is that the true mean is LTE 0
autumn observed mean  +1.7, gaussian dist p-value 0.004, t-dist p-value 0.008
winter observed mean  -1.3, gaussian dist p-value 0.978, t-dist p-value 0.969
```

`LTE zero, Autumn`

When the observed mean is positive (and not supportive of the hypothesis) the usual effect is observed that the t-dist p-value is greater. From the Gaussian p-value there is a strong rejection of the hypothesis and from the t-dist p-value there is a weaker rejection. This aligns with intuition because the t-dist represents more uncertainty so the rejection ought to be weaker.

`LTE zero, Winter`

When the observed mean is negative (and supportive of the hypothesis) the t-dist p-value is actually smaller. From the Gaussian p-value there is strong support. From the t-dist p-value there is weaker support. This aligns with intuition because the t-dist represents more uncertainty so the support ought to be weaker.

Note that in the last case (LTE zero, Winter), the uncertainty of the t-dist makes the p-value go in the direction opposite to what was observed in the other cases.

Is this description of an intuitive understanding correct despite the last case being different? A good answer would explain why the last case is or is not an anomaly.

Comment: t-test is used when we have a Normal distribution in our sample and we don’t know the true variance. Since the sample variance is not smaller than the true variance then i think your logic is right. There is more uncertainty while using t-test.

Answer (score 2):

In the last case, where the question is whether the data supports the claim that the winter mean is less than or equal to zero, it appears that you are doing a one sided test and reporting $1 - p$, where $p = Pr(\bar{X}_{winter} \le -1.3)$ assuming than $\mu_{winter}=0$. When reporting one-sided $p$ values, $p$ is the value that is typically reported.

```
winter <- c(-7, 1, -2.5, -2, 1, 2, -3.5, -4, -1, 2.5, -1, -5.5, -2, 1, 0, -3, 1.5)
1 - pnorm(mean(winter), 0, sd(winter)/sqrt(n))
[1] 0.9775428
1 - t.test(x=winter, alternative = "less")$p.value
[1] 0.968934
```

That $p$ is *larger* ($1-p$ smaller) for the $t$ version  is expected because $t$ distributions have "fatter tails". The plot below illustrates this; the normal distribution is more concentrated around its mode, whereas the $t$ distribution has more mass out in the tails of the distribution.

R code:

```
winter <- c(-7, 1, -2.5, -2, 1, 2, -3.5, -4, -1, 2.5, -1, -5.5, -2, 1, 0, -3, 1.5)
n <- length(winter)
x <- seq(-2,2,0.01)
df <- n-1
colors <- c("red", "black")
labels <- c("t(df=16)", "normal")
se <- sd(winter)/sqrt(n)
plot(x, dnorm(x, 0, se), type="l", lty=2, xlab="sample mean",
     ylab="", yaxt='n', main="comparison of null sampling distributions")
lines(x, 1/se * dt(x/se,df), lwd=2, col=colors[i])
legend("topright", title="",
       labels, lwd=2, lty=c(1, 2), col=colors)
abline(v=mean(winter))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no anomaly.

A p-value of 1.0 is extreme and it means support for the hypothesis being tested.

A p-value of 0.0 is extreme and it means rejection of the hypothesis being tested.

A p-value of 0.5 is moderate and it is consistent with uncertainty.

Greater uncertainty doesn't necessarily mean a greater p-value; it means a p-value closer to 0.5. Since the t-distribution is consistent with greater uncertainty compared to the Gaussian distribution, the p-value of the t-distribution will tend to be closer to 0.5 under the same procedural and computational circumstances.

In all 4 of the described cases, the p-value of the t-distribution is closer to 0.5. Under this intuition there is no anomaly.